# How to put out-of-scope element into the scope using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm designing a touch scrollable simple menu like below:

```
+-------+
|       |
|       |
|     ^ |
| # | % | @ | & |
+-------+
```

I did it using [simple CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16999868/1743124). I'm also able to get the active menu item in my dynamic webpage, so I can highlight them accordingly.

If the visitor is in `%` page, I can highlight that particular menu, if in `&` page, I can highlight that too. But the problem is, on the newly rendered page, the menu refreshes itself and `&` become out-of-scope again. Even it is highlighted, the user is unable to see *that* without touching and scrolling the menu.

```
+-------+
|       |
|       |
|       |     ^
| # | % | @ | & |
+-------+
```

Is there a way I can let the menu remember it's position so that it can refresh remembering its current position?

#### Edit

What I want is to let the menu remember its position while being in newly rendered page:

```
      +-------+
      |       |
      |       |
      |     ^ |
# | % | @ | & |
      +-------+
```

Comment: you can use cookies to store its position..

Comment: [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)... Many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507299/use-jquery-cookie-to-remember-menu-position

Comment: edited my question to make it more specific